# how to get tag from node in c# window form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, treeview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVTBz.png)How I can get the full path that exist in the tag of the node (in TreeView hierarchy)?

```
private void treeView_root_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Node.Parent == null) { }
   if (e.Node.Parent != null && *e.Node.Parent.Text == "test"*){ }
}
```

In the condition, I want to use the current directory, instead of `test`. The current directory's full path is already in `Tag`. The question is, how can I get the path from `Tag` so as to move forward into the directory?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwncJ.png)

Comment: can you also paste code showing **how the tag is set**?

Comment: Why `NodeMoouseClick`? What about cases that node will be selected by keyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sir, i want to explore directory sub sub folders and display files and folders from selected Node of the treeView.

Comment: Node.Tag.Fullpath.....i want this@RezaAghaei

Comment: @RezaAghaei kindly check image link on the top of Question

Answer (score 0):

`Node.Tag` is type of `object` so you must do cast to type, in which you saved it to it.

Example:

```
Node.Tag = "This is node tag"

string nodeTag = Node.Tag as String;
```

Or:

```
Node.Tag = 123

string nodeTag = (int) Node.Tag;
```

Comment: It is not in `Tag` property. You can get FullPath from specific node like this: `string path = Node.FullPath`

Comment: you are right but i don't want this Node.FullPath ...i am trying to get fullpath from TAG property FullPath

Comment: please check image from link on the top of edited question